# Как создать файл и узнать что он существует?

Tags: java, android, файлы

Как создать файл и проверить есть ли он. Прикреплю код. (Если уже доходили до этого момента, до достижение не нужно, если первый раз, то соответственно достижение должно появится)

```
public void showToast(View view) {




    String fileDir = "file";
    File f = new File(fileDir);
    if (f.exists()) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        try {
            new File(fileDir).createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Получена первая награда!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        LinearLayout toastContainer = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
        ImageView RewardImage = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        RewardImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.reward);
        toastContainer.addView(RewardImage, 0);
        toast.show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Не работает. Подскажите что сделать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Проверьте что разрешение на запись у приложения есть. И расскажите, почему последние пару дней столько народу спрашивает как файлы создавать)

Comment: Разрешение на запись я не добавлял. Как его сделать?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Лучше создавайте файл в приватной директории приложения `context.getFilesDir()`. Для этого не нужны никакие разрешения и этот файл не будет виден для других приложений.

Comment: Студенты зачеты сдают

Answer (score 0):

Для сохранения файлов лучше использовать директорию приложения - как это упоминал `eugeneek`, для ее получения можно воспользоваться: `context.getFilesDir()` (Если подчеркивает красным и непонятно почему - изучите что есть `context` - по русски с примерами здесь: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/context.php).

Ваш код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
String pathToFile = getFilesDir() + "\\";
String fileName = "file;

File f = new File(pathToFile + fileName);
if (f.exists()){
    ...
}else{
    try {
        new File(pathToFile + fileName).createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Наконец-то код заработал